# Use mod_rewrite to take part of the subdomain and append it to the url

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Is it possible to use **mod_rewrite** to take part of the subdomain from url and append it to the url?

This is the current url, where i have multiple subdomains one for each customer:

```
customername.subdomain.domain.co.uk
```

which I am going to point to a new server and new site. The new url format is:

```
http://domain/login/customername
```

as all customer are now all under one site.

So what i trying to do is use mod_rewrite to take the whatever before `.subdomain` and put it at the end of `https://domain/login/customername`

This is what i have got so far:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-z0-9]+).subdomain.domain(.*)$ [NC] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} $1/   
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://domain/login/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-z0-9-]+).subdomain.domain(.*)$ [NC] 
RewriteRule .* https://domain/login/%1 [L]
```

***Trick is:*** `%1` *is match* `$1` *from previous line...*

Comment: This would be better with some explanation of what's different and why.

Comment: Don't tell me...i know this stuff.  :)  Add it to the answer.